# Change order of wrapped items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to change the order of wrapped items

initial state is like this, all items are on one row

```
--------------  ------  --------   -----
|     1       | |  2 | |    3   | |  4  |
```

and after resizing

```
--------------  ------  -----
|     1       | |  2 | |  4  |
 -------
|   3  |
```

on further resizing

```
--------------  ------
|     1       | |  2  |
 -------         -----
|   3  |        |  4  |
```

I tried conditionally set the order attribute which kinda works but you can see it change order and afterwards wrap, so its kinda jumping.

Comment: Research [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and/or [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: I am trying with flexbox but getting nowhere so far.

Comment: In that case please edit your question to include your code so that we can help you to debug it